# Data binding in UI5

Tags: xml, data-binding, sapui5, ui5-webcomponents

I have an data output from an api as below In the jsonModel samplemodel :

```
[ 
{
“Info” : { Id: “id1”, val: [.      {id:”subid1”,name : “name1”}]}
},
{
“Info” : { Id: “id2”, val: [.     {id:”subid2”,name : “name2”}]}
}
]
```

How do I display by binding the values to sap.m.table . Tried the following

```
<Table     items=“{path:’samplemodel>/‘ }”
  <Text text:“{samplemodel>/info>id}”>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <Text text:“{samplemodel>info/id}”>
```